# Using ShiftRows to Rotate Values in List in Python

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to circularly shift the rows in each block in the following fashion. The first row remains the same. Shift the second row one position to the left. Shift the third row two positions to the left. Finally, shift the fourth row three positions to the left.

How do I do this?

```
Input: Output:

WVOG WVOG

JTXQ TXQJ

HUHX HXHU

ICWY YICW
_________

YMGH YMGH

TRKQ RKQT

HQPW PWHQ

KYVG GKYV
__________

LPYS LPYS

PWGO WGOP

INTO TOIN

FOPM MFOP
_________

OAAA OAAA

AAAA AAAA

AAAA AAAA

AAAA AAAA
_________
```

Let me know if this doesn't make sense

Comment: Your title is misleading. The AES algorithm has a step where rows of bytes are shifted in the manner you describe ([The ShiftRows step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#The_ShiftRows_step)), but that doesn't mean that you're using AES to perform that shifting operation. And you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: My fault, i will try to edit it.

Comment: Ok. But you still haven't actually asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
bloqs=['WVOG','JTXQ','HUHX']
i=0
for row in bloqs:
  for d in range(i):
    row = row[1:] + row[0]
  print(row)
  i = i + 1
```

Comment: This does not work the way i am looking for. This changes the last two of every input, instead of going in order from 1,2,3.